# React Native how to detect link form string and convert to a link?

Tags: react-native

I'd like the user to be able to grab a link from a comment (string), similar to link.

**Is there a simple way to do this**?

I believe it is addressed here (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3148),

But I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying you just need to parse a string of text and pull out any links that are in the string?

Comment: Hi Nader, yes, we'd like to detect any links in a string (a comment to a post) and use LinkingIOS to make it clickable.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [react-native-hyperlink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hyperlink):

```jsx
import Hyperlink from 'react-native-hyperlink'
import {Text, Linking} from 'react-native'

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Hyperlink onPress={Linking.openURL}>
    <Text>{"Click on https://stackoverflow.com to test"}</Text>
  </Hyperlink>
)
```

Comment: What about mobile number? my text is like tel:12312321

Comment: Try react-native-autolink as suggested below

Comment: `<Hyperlink linkDefault={ true }>` is easier to deal with. The `Linking` lib was giving me some error I couldn't find online about `validateURL` not existing. And you can add in `linkStyle={ { color: "blue" } }` to make it highlight the links like one would expect.

Answer (score 6):

I made a [quick demo](https://rnplay.org/apps/aGuDIQ) based on the component that was in the [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3148#issuecomment-144447164).

I couldn't test LinkingIOS in that environment but these [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linkingios.html#triggering-app-links) should get you there.

Here's the raw source:

```
var HyperText = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    // Check if nested content is a plain string
    if (typeof this.props.children === 'string') {

      // Split the content on space characters
      var words = this.props.children.split(/\s/);

      // Loop through the words
      var contents = words.map(function(word, i) {

        // Space if the word isn't the very last in the set, thus not requiring a space after it
        var separator = i < (words.length - 1) ? ' ' : '';

        // The word is a URL, return the URL wrapped in a custom <Link> component
        if (word.match(/^https?\:\//)) {
          return <Link key={i} url={word}>{word}{separator}</Link>;
        // The word is not a URL, return the word as-is
        } else {
          return word + separator;
        }
      });
    // The nested content was something else than a plain string
    // Return the original content wrapped in a <Text> component
    } else {
      console.log('Attempted to use <HyperText> with nested components. ' +
                   'This component only supports plain text children.');
      return <Text>{this.props.children}</Text>;
    }

    // Return the modified content wrapped in a <Text> component
    return (
      <Text>
        {contents}
      </Text>
    );
  }

});

var Link = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return <Text onPress={this.openUrl.bind(this, this.props.url)}>{this.props.children}</Text>;
  },

  openUrl: function(url) {
    LinkingIOS.canOpenURL(url, (supported) => {
      if (!supported) {
        AlertIOS.alert('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
      } else {
        LinkingIOS.openURL(url);
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Hope this somewhat helps.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that you are loosing the text formatting - new lines, tabs, etc. :(

Comment: Here is something that works very well: https://github.com/obipawan/react-native-hyperlink

Answer (score 5):

Try this library [react-native-autolink](https://github.com/joshswan/react-native-autolink) wherein it can detect whether it's a `hyperlink`, `hashtag`, `mention`, `email`, or `phone number`.

```
import Autolink from 'react-native-autolink';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Autolink
            text="This is the string to parse for urls (https://github.com/joshswan/react-native-autolink), phone numbers (415-555-5555), emails (josh@example.com), mentions/handles (@twitter), and hashtags (#exciting)"
            hashtag="instagram"
            mention="twitter"
        />
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: linkify-it, paired with react-native-hyperlink, works for this too, but with much more setup. I'm not sure if rn autolink works for nested text children, which I need.

Comment: This is the best one imo

Answer (score 2):

you can use this package to convert a string into the link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-linkify

`<Linkify>
  See source code at https://github.com/tasti/react-linkify/.
</Linkify>`

it will render

See source code at https://github.com/tasti/react-linkify/.

Comment: So easy. Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't the OP asking to make it work in React Native? This only works in web.